# Extracting data from a multipage PDF to excel by clicking text boxes in PDF with Python

Tags: python, excel, pdf

I'm trying to extract data from a pdf to excel, by clicking the text boxes in the pdf with the needed data. The pdf will have multiple pages in the same format. I'm thinking by clicking the text boxes on one page, the coordinates can be saved and applied to each page. The data is not in table formats. So far I've accomplished being able to choose the number of fields, name them, and add those to excel as headers on row 1. The excel file file is created correctly, but I cannot get a PDF to open. Ideally a file explorer opens up after naming the fields, then I navigate to it and open. I guess the idea after that is to have one button available for each field named. Click the button for the field to associate it with, then click the text box in the PDF to extract the data from. Any ideas are appreciated!

I'm not really sure how much to post.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QSpacerItem, QSizePolicy
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import openpyxl  # Make sure openpyxl is installed

class PDFExtractorApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle('PDF Text Extractor')
        self.setGeometry(100,  100,  800,  900)  # Window dimensions

        self.field_name_inputs = []  # Initialize here for class-wide access
        self.initializeUI()

    def initializeUI(self):
        self.welcome_label = QLabel('Welcome to the PDF Extractor! Choose the number of fields to be extracted.', self)
        self.welcome_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        font = self.welcome_label.font()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.welcome_label.setFont(font)

        self.num_fields_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.num_fields_label = QLabel('Enter the number of fields:', self)
        font = self.num_fields_label.font()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.num_fields_label.setFont(font)
        
        self.num_fields_input = QLineEdit(self)
        font = self.num_fields_input.font()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.num_fields_input.setFont(font)
        self.num_fields_input.setFixedSize(50,  30)  # Set fixed size for the input field

        self.num_fields_layout.addStretch()
        self.num_fields_layout.addWidget(self.num_fields_label)
        self.num_fields_layout.addWidget(self.num_fields_input)
        self.num_fields_layout.addStretch()

        self.continue_button = QPushButton('Continue', self)
        font = self.continue_button.font()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.continue_button.setFont(font)
        self.continue_button.setFixedSize(120,  40)  # Set fixed size for the continue button
        self.continue_button.clicked.connect(self.prepare_field_name_inputs)

        self.continue_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.continue_layout.addStretch()
        self.continue_layout.addWidget(self.continue_button)
        self.continue_layout.addStretch()

        self.main_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.welcome_label)
        self.main_layout.addItem(QSpacerItem(20,  50, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Fixed))
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.num_fields_layout)
        self.main_layout.addLayout(self.continue_layout)
        self.main_layout.addSpacerItem(QSpacerItem(20,  40, QSizePolicy.Minimum, QSizePolicy.Expanding))

        self.main_widget = QWidget()
        self.main_widget.setLayout(self.main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

    def prepare_field_name_inputs(self):
        try:
            num_fields = int(self.num_fields_input.text())
            if num_fields <=  0:
                raise ValueError
            self.show_field_names_input(num_fields)
        except ValueError:
            self.num_fields_input.setText('')
            self.num_fields_input.setPlaceholderText('Please enter a valid positive integer')

    def show_field_names_input(self, num_fields):
        self.clearLayout(self.main_layout)
        
        self.main_layout.addWidget(self.welcome_label)
        self.field_name_inputs = []  # Reset the list to handle new input fields

        for i in range(num_fields):
            row_layout = QHBoxLayout()
            label = QLabel(f'Field {i +   1}:', self)
            font = label.font()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            label.setFont(font)
            
            input = QLineEdit(self)
            font = input.font()
            font.setPointSize(12)
            input.setFont(font)
            input.setFixedSize(200,   30)

            row_layout.addStretch()
            row_layout.addWidget(label)
            row_layout.addWidget(input)
            row_layout.addStretch()

            self.main_layout.addLayout(row_layout)
            self.field_name_inputs.append(input)

        self.header_continue_button = QPushButton('Open PDF', self)
        font = self.header_continue_button.font()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.header_continue_button.setFont(font)
        self.header_continue_button.setFixedSize(120,   40)
        self.header_continue_button.clicked.connect(self.create_excel_file)

        # Create a QHBoxLayout to center the button
        button_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        button_layout.addStretch()  # Add space before the button
        button_layout.addWidget(self.header_continue_button)  # Add the button
        button_layout.addStretch()  # Add space after the button

        # Add the button layout to the main layout
        self.main_layout.addLayout(button_layout)
        self.main_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    def create_excel_file(self):
        workbook = openpyxl.Workbook()
        sheet = workbook.active
        
        for i, input_field in enumerate(self.field_name_inputs):
            sheet.cell(row=1, column=i+1).value = input_field.text()

        workbook.save('extracted_data.xlsx')
        self.notify_user_excel_created()

    def notify_user_excel_created(self):
        self.clearLayout(self.main_layout)
        success_label = QLabel('Excel file created successfully with the specified headers.', self)
        font = success_label.font()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        success_label.setFont(font)
        self.main_layout.addWidget(success_label)

    def clearLayout(self, layout):
        while layout.count():
            item = layout.takeAt(0)
            widget = item.widget()
            if widget is not None:
                widget.deleteLater()
            else:
                if item.layout() is not None:
                    self.clearLayout(item.layout())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = PDFExtractorApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```